# M14 cordapp-template-kotlin Node error - Failed to find a store

Tags: corda

This is in the web log. Shall we be concerned even though it seems things are running?

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to create NettyConnector for localhost:10005
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.start(NettyConnector.java:494) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.openTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1034) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.createTransportConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1076) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.establishNewConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:1254) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnection(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:891) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.getConnectionWithRetry(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:795) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ClientSessionFactoryImpl.connect(ClientSessionFactoryImpl.java:238) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.client.impl.ServerLocatorImpl.createSessionFactory(ServerLocatorImpl.java:772) [artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$sessionAndProducerPool$1.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:146) [corda-rpc-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler$sessionAndProducerPool$1.invoke(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:60) [corda-rpc-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.LazyPool.borrow(LazyPool.kt:42) [corda-core-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClientProxyHandler.start(RPCClientProxyHandler.kt:423) [corda-rpc-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:155) [corda-rpc-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient$start$1.invoke(RPCClient.kt:88) [corda-rpc-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtilsKt.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:161) [corda-core-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.core.internal.InternalUtilsKt.logElapsedTime(InternalUtils.kt:153) [corda-core-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.internal.RPCClient.start(RPCClient.kt:142) [corda-rpc-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.client.rpc.CordaRPCClient.start(CordaRPCClient.kt:62) [corda-rpc-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.connectLocalRpcAsNodeUser(NodeWebServer.kt:202) [corda-webserver-impl-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.retryConnectLocalRpc(NodeWebServer.kt:180) [corda-webserver-impl-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.internal.NodeWebServer.start(NodeWebServer.kt:43) [corda-webserver-impl-0.14.0.jar:?]
    at net.corda.webserver.WebServer.main(WebServer.kt:61) [corda-webserver-impl-0.14.0.jar:?]
Caused by: java.lang.Exception: Failed to find a store at /Users/johnz/Project/cordapp-template-kotlin/build/nodes/NodeA/certificates/sslkeystore.jks
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.validateStoreURL(SSLSupport.java:148) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadKeystore(SSLSupport.java:101) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.loadKeyManagers(SSLSupport.java:123) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.ssl.SSLSupport.createContext(SSLSupport.java:52) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    at org.apache.activemq.artemis.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnector.start(NettyConnector.java:490) ~[artemis-core-client-2.1.0.jar:2.1.0]
    ... 21 more
```

Answer (score 0):

No, I wouldn't be concerned unless you start seeing weird behaviour. The node will regenerate its store automatically on start-up if it can't find one.

Without being sure, this may be related to upgrading your version of Corda. The node's internal organisation is still in flux.